# Extended class does not see property of parent Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, oop

I call a CodeIgniter controller method -imgupload- from jquery ajax. This controller extends my custom front controller.

```
class newad extends My_Controller{

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}
public function imageupload() {
    $this->load->library("uploadhandler"); 
}
```

The imgupload method calls the uploadhandler class which extends from newad.

```
class uploadhandler extends newad {
```

The functionality of that class works properly, except for one thing, I cant access the properties of the My_Controller class, even though they are declared protected.
The inheritance chain looks like this: My_Controller->newad->uploadhandler.

Any idea why I cant access those properties?

Comment: Why you need to extend a controller for a library?

Comment: I need to know the user ID from the db in that library. The user ID is stored as a property of the front controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short the answer is you do not need to extend Controller class here. You can just pass the value to your library as a parameter.

```
$params = array('user_ud' => $this->userID, 'otehr' => 'other');    
$this->load->library('uploadhandler', $params);

//Now from your library
class uploadhandler{

    public function __construct($params)
    {
        // Do something with $params
    }

   //.. Your code...//
}
```

Now about your question:

> The functionality of that class works properly, except for one thing, I cant access the properties of the My_Controller class, even though they are declared protected. The inheritance chain looks like this: My_Controller->newad->uploadhandler. Any idea why I cant access those properties?

As inheritance chain are ok, you can access property of My_Controller from your library but not the value of the Current controller, because these two are different *object*.

So here is my answer how can we access the value? One way I have already mentioned. That will be enough if you need to share some property with the library. But what if you need to access all the Controller **instance**. There is a function to get the reference of controller  instance `get_instance()`. You can use this function anywhere and get access of all public property controller. If you need to access any private property of controller the define a geter function to access that.

---

### Explanation

First of all you need to learn basic about [**OOP**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming#Fundamental_features_and_concepts). Learn about Class, Object, Inheritance..

When I said property of My_controller is different from the same property the you accessed from  *uploadhandler*, it may confused you if you are not familiar with class and object. Here is two instance(object) of different class.
For short let say you have some classes like: **Vehicle**, **Car**, **Machine** and **Person**. All they have common attributes say *name*, *weight* ..

> So, can we just inherit Any of these class from other??

Simple answer is no. We can't(!) define a Person class extending from Others. So how can we decide which incoherence would legal. If you can say **Foo** is a **Bar** you can write **Foo** class extending from Bar. Now from your case, It is obvious **uploadhandler** is not a controller. So  **Never** Extend a *anything* from *something* that is not *something*.

**NB: The answer is generic. If you need any specific clarification, just ask, I can update my answer**